# Ubuntu 18.04 dual monitor doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I used to run 17.10 and things were working perfectly. when i upgraded the second monitor stopped working. It works just fine in windows but I don't want to use windows. I have a AMD RX 480 as my graphics card.

I upgraded my kernel to the latest stable kernel (4.17.9-041709-generic) and I upgraded the mesa to the newest one. unfortunately neither of those things helped. I also also went into the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and changed the set wayland to false and that didn't work either. When I go into recovery mode for this kernel version it works but it doesn't load into gnome. It gets stuck.

Here is my xrandr:

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-A-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)


$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:122 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dfe00000-dfe3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: did you install/upgrade the amd driver?

Comment: it  is automatically installed in the kernel. anyway yes i did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Changing Display Manager from gdm3 to lightdm solved the problem in my case.

Install LightDM

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Run `dpkg-reconfigure` and select `lightdm` in the dialog

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Noteworthy that I have the latest available Nvidia driver installed:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers
devices : 
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
driver : nvidia-driver-430 distro non-free recommended
```